# Is it possible to run cuMemset on a CUarray?

Tags: cuda, memset, cuda-driver, cuda-arrays

I have a CUarray that I got from my OpenGL-context via cuGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(). Is there a possiblity to use it with cuMemset*()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. You can't get a device pointer into a CUDA array (to pass to cuMemset*()), and NVIDIA has never shipped a memset function for CUDA arrays.

You have to zero out some host memory and do a memcpy (or memcpy's) into the CUDA array, or (if your app runs only on SM 2.0 or later) roll your own with surface stores.

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean with the second proposal "roll your own with surface stores"? Do you mean writing a kernel that uses surf3Dwrite to clear the array?

Comment: Yes, that is just what I was proposing - and happily, because surface load/store are untyped, you can write a templated function to store any size operand.  See section 10.9.2 in the Texturing chapter of the CUDA handbook for an example in 2D. http://www.cudahandbook.com/uploads/Chapter_10._Texturing.pdf

Comment: Thanks! I implemented both methods and prefer the cuMemcpyAtoA-method over the kernel because it runs significantly faster!

Comment: If your CUDA array is attached to a renderbuffer or a texture that is part of a framebuffer object in OpenGL you could also initialize it by rendering `glClear(<value>,...)`. This is the approach I've used and it seems to run very quickly.